# How do I pass a useState function into a component from context?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-state, use-context

I am trying to create a useState function in my context and provider files so that it can be used in several components. I've used this in other code before, but it doesn't seem to work here.

**StudentContext.ts**

```
import { createContext } from "react";
import Student from "../models/Student";

export interface StudentContextModel {
  students: Student[];
  setStudents: (students: Student[]) => void;
}

const defaultValue: StudentContextModel = {
  students: [],
  setStudents: () => {},
};
const StudentContext = createContext(defaultValue);
export default StudentContext;
```

**StudentContextProvider.tsx**

```
import { ReactNode, useState } from "react";
import StudentContext from "./StudentContext";
import Student from "../models/Student";

function StudentContextProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  const [students, setStudents] = useState<Student[]>([]);

  return (
    <StudentContext.Provider
      value={{
        students,
        setStudents,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </StudentContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default StudentContextProvider;
```

**StudentList.tsx**

```
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import StudentContext from "../context/StudentContext";
import "./StudentList.css";

const StudentList = () => {
  const { students, setStudents } = useContext(StudentContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    setStudents([
      {
        id: "abc123",
        pic: "https://d23.com/app/uploads/2013/04/1180w-600h_a-to-z-tron.jpg",
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "smith",
        email: "string@string.string",
        skill: "flailing with",
        city: "NY",
        company: "jobs inc.",
        grades: ["75", "60"],
      },
    ]);
  }, []);

  return <div className="StudentList">{students[0]?.firstName}</div>;
};

export default StudentList;
```

The useState declaration in provider does seem to be valid because if I give `students` a `defaultValue`, that gets passed through, but when I try to call `setStudents` inside of a component, it does not overwrite the defaultValue. There are no errors anywhere.

I've also tried to use

```
export interface StudentContextModel {
  students: Student[];
  setStudents: Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Student[]>>;
}
```

inside of the context file, but it seems to make zero difference. Similarly, I've also tried changing `setStudents: () => {},` to `setStudents: () => [],`. I assumed that that wouldn't change anything because useState functions return void, the brackets wouldn't really matter, and I was correct. In each of my alternatives, there are zero errors and the defaultValue of students is never overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a doofus and forgot to wrap the component inside of the context provider.

before:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Homepage />
    </div>
  );
}
```

After:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <StudentContextProvider>
        <Homepage />
      </StudentContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```